# Blocking an Android thread with a dialog

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an Android application that connects to Bluetooth devices somewhat freely.  When I attempt to connect to a device that isn't paired with the phone, a dialog will prompt the user for a passkey.  The passkey is known a priori, but as there is no method to programatically enter it (in the standard Android APIs at least), it must be shown to the user then entered.

What I have presently is a thread that initiates a connection by grabbing a `BluetoothSocket` and calling `.connect()` on it.  If pairing is required, that call will block until the user enters a passkey in the dialog.

In order to preempt that, I added to my activity's handler something to display dialogs.  Before sending the message I made a dummy object to pass along, and between sending the message and attempting to connect, called `.wait()` on it, figuring that I could `.notify()` after receiving an `OnClick` from the dialog, however I'm unable to refer to the handled message in the inner `AlertDialog` class, as is the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028697/dialogs-alertdialogs-how-to-block-execution-while-dialog-is-up-net-style).

I could have it do a call back up to the class holding the thread, but it seems a little clunky, leading me to the core question: *is my structure fundamentally broken?  How should I go about it?*

[Another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027149/popup-dialog-android-from-background-thread) suggests to use the notification system, however it seems much better design here to mirror the passkey dialog with another dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think Romain Guy's answer in the link you provided might help.  You can pass information between Activities as needed.

[Dialogs / AlertDialogs: How to "block execution" while dialog is up (.NET-style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028697/dialogs-alertdialogs-how-to-block-execution-while-dialog-is-up-net-style/2029128#2029128)

Answer (score 0):

Don't block, just implement `Interfaces` and Fire using them (interface = listener),

1. search
2. select a device
3. connect:
4. if the device is paired then connect.
5. if not paired show dialog, and on positive click, connect.

> BWT, i think you need to extend Dialog, and implements your own methods, to hold some information about the Device you are trying to pair with, and i prefer you implements Own Interface too.