# Android - How to implement a Login-Dialog for a background thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dialog, roboguice

Im working with Android 2.1, RoboGuice 1.1 and Guice 2.0 (without aop).
My app has a background thread that gets started in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` which connects to a server and might need the user to provide credentials for logging in.

At first I found the `PopupWindow` in the API but I read [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027149/popup-dialog-android-from-background-thread) that it shouldn't be used for that.

So I tried to inject my `Activity` into my background thread and to open a `Dialog` in a `Runnable` passed to [Activity.runOnUIThread(Runnable r)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) but unfortunately roboguice is creating a new instance of my activity when injecting it into my background thread.

I now assume the correct way of implementing a Login-Dialog would be to send an `Intent` to my activity and let it show the `Dialog`. Furthermore I assume that the `Activity` needs to send an `Intent` (containing the credentials) back to the background thread.
*Is this correct or is there a more elegant way of doing that?*

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver) I found how to register a receiver for the `Intent`. But on which `Activity` instance should I call `registerReceiver` within the background thread?

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to inject myActivity into my background thread"? Is that roboguice terminology?

Comment: My background thread is created by RoboGuice as it's a simple POJO. Within this class there is a field `@Inject private MyActivity mainActivity;` that also gets set by RoboGuice.

Comment: If `runOnUiThread` is not an option, then I think what you need is not an Intent but a Handler.

Comment: And I can't understand how that robo-thing is preventing you from holding references. It has to be a way to pass a reference to your thread!

Comment: Ok. I think I found a solution. I can obtain a reference to my Application instance and register a BroadcastReceiver on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create an inner class in the activity that uses RoboAsyncTask and basically has access to the activity. That works well for me. If you need to be able to login from different activities you make it a top level class and pass the fragment or activity instance into the async task constructor and do the ui updates in onSuccess.