# Display pop up window on top of any app

Tags: android

I have been using an application called Viber on my Android 4.4.2 phone. I notice that this app can show a new chat message by opening a window on top of any currently running app.

Can some one tell how this is done in Android ? Any sample tutorial ?

Comment: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/ is a pretty simple example

Comment: See the answer to a similar question: [Popup dialog android from background thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027149/popup-dialog-android-from-background-thread)